# Razor pages: How to dynamically change button properties (color,text) to reflect backend changes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, razor-pages

In a non-Razor environment with simple HTML, CSS and AJAX, easily done, but from within Razor Pages?

Let's say I have a simple button based on a backend state of (success,danger) like:

```
<div id="UpdateButonStatusEvery2s">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
</div>
```

and I want to reflect a change in the backend state to "danger" in the button

```
<div id="UpdateButonStatusEvery2s">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
</div>
```

How do I achieve that?

I figured I have to run the usual `setinterval()` in AJAX, but how do I get the Razor backend to respond with the HTML fragment `id="UpdateButonStatusEvery2s"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code in your razor-page.

First add this code in your startup:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

Then in your razor:

```
@page
@model ButtonDemoModel 
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div id="UpdateButonStatusEvery2s">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="success">Success</button>
</div>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $("button").click(function (e) {
            var data = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "?handler=test",
                data: { data: data },
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.result == "danger")
                    {
                        var newRow = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="danger">' + response.result +'</button>';
                        $('#UpdateButonStatusEvery2s').html(newRow);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

The backend code:

```
 public class ButtonDemoModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public IActionResult OnPostTest(string data)
    {
        //here you can change the data,do your logic.
        data = "danger";
        return new JsonResult(new { result = data });
    }
}
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: It mostly does. At least I was fully able to device the full answer based on your excellent reply.
I augmented it by using a setinterval loop instead and giving the button an id so that multiple buttons can be individually handled.
Thanks again for a beautiful solution.
Karsten

Answer (score 0):

Similar effect can be accomplished from c# using `Task.ContinueWith()`

For example:

```
Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine("I'm back"));
```