# How to dynamically change Button Attr in Razor Page?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am trying to get a button to toggle between two states within MVC Razor View.

**Startup.cs (Configuring Antiforgery Service)**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
   services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

**View (with JS)**

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color: none">
        <button id="ms1" class="btn btn-primary">Misc Buttons 1</button>
        <button id="ms2" class="btn btn-success">Misc Buttons 2</button>
    </div>

    <div id="UpdateButonStatusEvery2s" style="background-color: none">
        <button id="btnPause" class="btn btn-danger" value="Pause">Pause</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-7" style="float: right; background-color: none">
        <button id="ms3" class="btn btn-info">Misc Buttons 3</button>        
        <button id="ms4" class="btn btn-success">Misc Buttons 4</button>
        <button id="ms5" class="btn btn-success">Misc Buttons 5</button>
        <button id="ms6" class="btn btn-danger">Misc Buttons 6</button>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnToggle").click(function (e) {
            alert("test");
            var data = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '../Home/OnPostTest/',
                data: { data: data },
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.result == "ToggleDanger") {
                        var newRow = '<button id="btnToggle" class="btn btn-success" value="Danger">Danger</button>';
                        $('#UpdateButonStatusEvery2s').html(newRow);
                    }
                    else if (response.result == "TogglePause") {
                        var newRow = '<button id="btnToggle" class="btn btn-danger" value="Pause">Pause</button>';
                        $('#UpdateButonStatusEvery2s').html(newRow);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult OnPostTest(string data)
{
    string responseData;

    if (data == "Danger")
    {
        responseData = "TogglePause";
        return new JsonResult(new { result = responseData });
    }
    else if (data == "Pause")
    {
        responseData = "ToggleDanger";
        return new JsonResult(new { result = responseData });
    }

    return new JsonResult(null);
}
```

With this, it can toggle from the `initial "Pause"` button to the `"Danger"` button. However, the updated div with the new danger button HTML does not recognize the button ID as `alert("test");` does not trigger at all upon clicking `"Danger" btn`.

It's based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66076356/razor-pages-how-to-dynamically-change-button-properties-color-text-to-reflect); however, as I am unsure how PageModel could be integrated, I opted for the regular Controller for `onPostTest`, which might be an XY Problem, but any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change your js like this:

```
$("#btnToggle").click(function () {
            alert("test");
            var data = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '../Home/OnPostTest/',
                data: { data: data },
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.result == "ToggleDanger") {
                        $('#btnToggle').removeClass('btn-danger');
                        $('#btnToggle').addClass('btn-success');
                        $('#btnToggle').html("Danger");
                        $('#btnToggle').attr("value","Danger");
                    }
                    else if (response.result == "TogglePause") {
                        $('#btnToggle').removeClass('btn-success');
                        $('#btnToggle').addClass('btn-danger');
                        $('#btnToggle').html("Pause");
                        $('#btnToggle').attr("value", "Pause");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

result:
[image]